# How to add noindex / nofollow robot metatags to Views subpages

Tags: views, meta-tags, 7

I have a big view with lots of filters, and Google and friends are killing one of my sites after a cache clear.

How could I add noindex and nofollow metatags in this views' subpages header? I would like to keep the views main page free of these tags.  As I understand the [Metatag](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) module is not yet up to the task.

Another idea just came to my mind: Adding nofollow to Views sorting links would achieve nearly the same.

I inquired and no such feature will happen in Views http://drupal.org/node/1758354

Answer (score 2):

Altering robots.txt could be an option. For example this would stop google from accessing your pager.

```
    # Disallow all URL variables except for page
    Disallow: /*?page=*&*
    Disallow: /*?page=0*
```

More examples on [Views and SEO can be found here.](http://drupal.org/node/345620)

Answer (score 0):

This solution now fails as any canned links to a filtered solution trigger google search index to consider the page important and flag the robots.txt, the robots noindex metatag is required to fix this alert in the google search console.  A method for adding the metatag to a filtered view is now REQUIRED for a site to function without an error alert.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/133966)